# Why can't a class method find an attribute that was defined in object initialization?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have built a PickleJar class that I intend to work like a dictionary (it will have a subset of dictionaries built-in methods, allowing it to be accessed like one). The twist is that when an object is added or deleted from the PickleJar, it will update a local copy on my laptop.

```
class PickleJar():
    '''
    Class used for storing objects locally. It is accessed like a dictionary, and anytime a new item is added,
    the pickled version of the dictionary is also updated on local disk.
    Example:
        jar = PickleJar()
        jar['ObjectId(18452298134587901458)'] = Object
    Args:
        name (str)  :   Name of the local pickle file which this class is bound to
        loc (str)   :   Location of the pickle file specified by name
    '''
    def __init__(self, name:str, loc=r'C:\Users\path\to\.pickle'):
        loc = Path(loc)
        jar_path = os.path.join(loc, Path(name))
        if os.path.exists(jar_path):
            with open(jar_path, 'rb') as fopen:
                temp = pickle.load(fopen)
            assert isinstance(temp, dict), "Expected a dict with key: value pairs of Key: Object"
            self.jar_path = jar_path
            self.__dict__ = temp
        else:
            self.jar_path = jar_path
            self.__dict__ = dict()

    def __setitem__(self, key:str, item:ConcurrentExecutionGraph):
        '''Any time this object has a key set to a value, it will update it in the local pickle dictionary'''
        with open(self.jar_path, 'rb') as fopen:
            disk_pickle = pickle.load(fopen)
            disk_pickle[key]=item
        with open(self.jar_path, 'wb') as fopen:
            pickle.dump(disk_pickle, fopen)
        self.__dict__[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        with open(self.jar_path, 'rb') as fopen:
            disk_pickle = pickle.load(fopen)
            del disk_pickle[key]
        with open(self.jar_path, 'wb') as fopen:
            pickle.dump(disk_pickle, fopen)
        del self.__dict__[key]

    def keys(self):
        return self.__dict__.keys()

    def values(self):
        return self.__dict__.values()

    def items(self):
        return self.__dict__.items()
```

The problem is that after the PickleJar is initialized and I try to call its `__setitem__` method, it complains that `self.jar_path` doesn't exist anymore, despite me setting that explicitly in `__init__`. I have verified by stepping through the code that `self.jar_path` DOES get set during initialization

```
Key = "SomeKey"
Object = "SomeObject"
basejar = PickleJar("BaselinePickleJar.pkl")
basejar[Key] = SomeObject
```

I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'PickleJar' object has no attribute 'jar_path'
  File "C:\Users\...\memory.py", line 426, in __setitem__
    with open(self.jar_path, 'rb') as fopen:
  File "C:\Users\...\memory.py", line 330, in __init__
    basejar[Key] = SomeObject
  File "C:\Users\...\train.py", line 39, in main
    data_manager = DataManager(args)
  File "C:\Users\...\train.py", line 134, in <module>
    main(args, kwargs)
```

Comment: `self.__dict__` contains all the attributes. When you assign this, you lose any attributes that aren't in the dictionary.

Comment: if you want to hold a hidden dict, name it `self._dict` or something, `__dict__` is already taken. Generally `__somename__` is a hint that Python internally uses the name for something (`__dict__` for holding instance attributes, `__next__` for iteration).

Comment: You are re-inveting the wheel, just use the built-in module [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html). Anyway, your problem is because you are using the instance `__dict__`... *why are you doing that*? Don't do that. Use another `dict` object, e.g. `self.data = {}`

Comment: Also, why, oh why, are you using `pathlib.Path` objects **but then using `os.path` functions with them**? The whole point is *to use the `pathlib.Path` API*, so instead of `os.path.join(loc, Path(name))` use `loc / name`, instead of `if os.path.exists(jar_path)` use `if jar_path.exists()`

Comment: Thanks @BatWannaBe , that's what I ended up doing !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `self.__dict__` replaces all the attributes with the items in the dictionary. So you're losing the value of `self.jar_path`.

The simple solution is to set `self.jar_path` *after* you set `self.__dict__`.

```
    def __init__(self, name:str, loc=r'C:\Users\path\to\.pickle'):
        loc = Path(loc)
        jar_path = os.path.join(loc, Path(name))
        if os.path.exists(jar_path):
            with open(jar_path, 'rb') as fopen:
                temp = pickle.load(fopen)
            assert isinstance(temp, dict), "Expected a dict with key: value pairs of Key: Object"
            self.__dict__ = temp
        else:
            self.__dict__ = dict()
        self.jar_path = jar_path
```

Comment: @JakeDaly The best solution would be to maintain a separate `dict` object and not abuse the instance `__dict__` this way